# How can I set type conditions on the implementation of a generic type?

Tags: typescript

I have the following code, where the intention is to only allow `Chart` objects where the `data` and `options` object types are paired correctly.  However, with this code, the TS compiler doesn't error at the case I was hoping to prevent.

```
class Chart<TData extends ChartData<TOptions>, TOptions extends ChartOptions> { 
    public data?: TData;
    public options?: TOptions;
}

interface ChartData<TOptions extends ChartOptions> { }
interface ChartOptions { }

interface BarChartData extends ChartData<BarChartOptions> { barChartData: number }
interface BarChartOptions extends ChartOptions { barChartOption: string }

interface PieChartData extends ChartData<PieChartOptions> { pieChartData: number }
interface PieChartOptions extends ChartOptions { pieChartOption: string}

const barChart = new Chart<BarChartData, BarChartOptions>();
const pieChart = new Chart<PieChartData, PieChartOptions>();

const mixedChart = new Chart<BarChartData, PieChartOptions>(); // expected compilation error

// the situation I'm trying to prevent:
mixedChart.data = { barChartData: 7 } as BarChartData;
mixedChart.options = {pieChartOption: 'hello' } as PieChartOptions

// BarChartData and PieChartOptions should not be able to mix
```

I'd like for options and data to be able to be updated separately (due to implementation specifics), which is why `ChartData` doesn't contain a property for options.  If I add `options: TOptions` as a property to `ChartData`, the error is triggered, so it appears the non-use of `TOptions` in `ChartData` is causing that type constraint to be ignored.

How can I keep this constraint intact without adding a property that I don't want used/exposed?

Comment: Why not use just one type argument on class `ChartData<TOptions extends ChartOptions>` then you won't have a problem like the above. [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WGXjKw)

Comment: @Eldar That doesn't appear to solve the issue, since I can still set `mixedChart.data = { barChartData: 7 } as BarChartData` without getting a compiler error.  I've updated the post with a slightly better example.

Comment: Fist one is because ChartData doesn't really depend on Options, anything extends {} which is ChartOptions<whatever>

Comment: And you will always be able to assign BarData to BarData no matter what

Comment: @Benjin you need a discriminator like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WYKbrN)

Comment: I got it working well-enough with a different approach that caught all the cases; reducing to one type argument caused some cases to be missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by adding `type?: ChartType` to the base class, and using that as the type parameter.  This succeeded because the type for each `type` in the implementing interfaces ended up being `bar | undefined` and `pie | undefined`, which were incompatible with each other.

The compiler realized those had to match once `type?: TChartType` was added in the chart-specific interfaces.  Unlike my original attempt of using TOptions, this is harmless if set or left unset, and far less likely to be confusing to any consumers.

```
class Chart<TChartType extends ChartType, TData extends ChartData<TChartType>, TOptions extends ChartOptions<TChartType>> { 
  public data?: TData;
  public options?: TOptions;
  type?: TChartType;
}

export type ChartType = 'bar' | 'pie' | 'line';

interface ChartData<TChartType extends ChartType> {
  type?: TChartType; // optional so that invokers don't actually have to set it
}

interface ChartOptions<TChartType extends ChartType> {
  type?: TChartType;
}

interface BarChartData extends ChartData<'bar'> { barChartData: number }
interface BarChartOptions extends ChartOptions<'bar'> { barChartOption: string }

interface PieChartData extends ChartData<'pie'> { pieChartData: number }
interface PieChartOptions extends ChartOptions<'pie'> { pieChartOption: string}

const barChart = new Chart<'bar', BarChartData, BarChartOptions>();
barChart.data = { barChartData: 7 }; // 'data' prop type is well-defined, 'type' prop can be ignored since that's just serving as a compiler hint

const mixedChart = new Chart<'bar', BarChartData, PieChartOptions>(); // error because PieChartOptions can't go with Bar charts
```